# How to connect a TA+ Database (Firebird) on Raspbian?

Tags: linux, firebird, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

we are currently using Safescan's TA+ Software on a Windows machine at work, but try to move the Database (TADATA.FDB) onto a small Linux Server, which is why we bought a Raspberry Pi2 and installed Raspbian and Firebird 2.5 Super on it. Afterwards we copied the TADATA.FDB File from the Windows 7 machine onto the Pi and set the SYSDBA password to "masterkey".

If I try to connect to said database on the Windows machine using

```
CONNECT "C:\Program Files (x86)\SafeScan\TA4\TADATA.FDB" user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey'
```

everything works fine and I can access the database. However, if I use the equivalent command

```
CONNECT "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/tadata.fdb" user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey'
```

on the Raspberry, I get the following response:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000
file /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/tadata.fdb is not a valid database
```

If I try to connect via the Safescan Software using the Syntax they provided ( SERVERIP:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/tadata.fdb ), the program gives me this error messeage:

```
The settings of the provided database couldn't be opened 
(Error: file /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/tadata.fdb is not a valid database
Connection authorization failure.
GDS Code: 335544323 Error Code: 3 )
```

The credentials I provided seem to be set correctly, as I can use them to create and connect any other Database, such as the sample one. To make sure the password is set correctly, I also used

```
GSEC> modify SYSDBA -pw masterkey
```

with root privileges.

What should I do to connect to this Database on the Raspberry?

EDIT:
The "show version" command gives the following info:
On the Raspbian (with a test.fdb connected):

```
ISQL Version: LI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5
Server version:
Firebird/linux ARM (access method), version "LI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5"
Firebird/linux ARM (remote server), version "LI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5/tcp (raspberrypi)/P12"
Firebird/linux ARM (remote interface), version "LI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5/tcp (raspberrypi)/P12"
on disk structure version 11.2
```

And on the Windows Version (with TADATA.FDB connected):

```
ISQL Version: WI-V2.5.4.26856 Firebird 2.5
Server Version:
Firebird/x86/Windows NT (access method), version "WI-V2.5.4.26856 Firebird 2.5"
Firebird/x86/Windows NT (remote server), version "WI-V2.5.4.26856 Firebird 2.5/XNet (WIN7PC)/P12"
Firebird/x86/Windows NT (remote interface), version "WI-V2.5.4.26856 Firebird 2.5/XNet (WIN7PC)/P12"
on disk sturcture version 10.1
```

Comment: FYI: putting SOLVED in the title is not encouraged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Comment: I have reverted your edit that added "SOLVED". You mark a question as solved by accepting the answer that solved the problem, if no such answer exists then by all means post your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a backup in transportable format with gbak on windows machine and restore it on raspberry pi machine, they have different cpus (x86 vs arm) and On-Disk Structure differs.

See the ["Firebird Backup & Restore Utility" manual](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gbak.html) for details on using gbak.

Comment: Using `nbackup.exe -U SYSDBA -P masterkey -B 0 E:\tadata.fdb E:\backup.nbk` I get the following error:
`[
PROBLEM ON "begin backup: commit".
feature is not supported
SQLCODE:-901
]
Failure: Database error`

Comment: you need to use gbak http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gbak.html nbackup is used mainly for backups with snapshots (Nbackup can't make transportable backups, that is: backups you can restore on an incompatible platform or under another server version.) http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nbackup-overview.html

Comment: Using gbak I was able to create an importable backup that also runs on the pi. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you get :

```
[ PROBLEM ON "begin backup: commit". feature is not supported SQLCODE:-901 ]
```

while running NBackup on your Firebird database, it could be because the database OSD is 10.1 and not 11.2.(use gstat to find out).

Install latest Firebird version then backup and restore your db with GBak.
NBackup will work after having done that.